# how to create custom tracking method in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

I create the Custom tracking method in magento 1.9
Only show Tracking method dropdown in backend but the popup not show my tracking method
Post service is my custom tracking method

[image]

[image]

```
 public function isTrackingAvailable()
    { 
     return true;
   }
```